# Change scope when rendering nested objects in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In Handlebars you can change the current scope, so if you have an object:

```
walrus: {
  bubbles: 7,
  zombies[
    {name: 'Jim', hobby: 'pinocle'},
    {name: 'Cassandra', hobby: 'privateering'},
    {name: 'Ke$ha', hobby: 'yelling'}
  ],
  address: {
    city: 'Fresno',
    state: 'CA'
  }
}
```

Then I can send that context to a template such as this:

```
<article class='walrus'>
  <h2>I have {{ bubbles }} bubbles!</h2>
  <ul>
    {{#each zombies}}
      <li>{{ name }} likes {{ hobby }}
    {{/each }}
  </ul>
  <div class='address'>
    {{#with address}}
      <p>{{city}}, {{state}}</p>
    {{/with}}
  </div>
</article>
```

But in Angular, if I set $scope.walrus = walrus, I end up with this:

```
<article class='walrus'>
  <h2>I have {{ walrus.bubbles }} bubbles!</h2>
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="zombie in walrus.zombies">{{ zombie.name }} likes {{ zombie.hobby }}
  </ul>
  <div class='address'>
    <p>{{walrus.address.city}}, {{walrus.address.state}}</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Is there a way to have Angular recognize what scope it is in, and not require the extra `walrus.`, `zombie.`, or (worst of all) `walrus.address.`?

Comment: You mean you want to use the same template with different scopes right? What use case do you have in mind? My first idea are directives or simply different routes but I am not sure if that's what you are looking for :)

Comment: I have an object similar to the example object with nested objects. If I want to have a walrus#show view, then I need to render all of this information (so not on another route) but typing out the nested objects is putting major clutter into my views! Admittedly a style thing, but look at that unnecessarily awkward `.address p`!

Comment: easy to move the `clutter` to a directive  [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3psx921S4AO7w6s2NboZ?p=preview)

Comment: @charlietfl adding a bunch of html strings together in JS isn't a more  elegant solution than the original. That approach is unmaintainable.

Comment: strings can be placed in a template url also. Can be in script tag, or remote html file

Comment: I don't see much of a difference between writing .address.city and {{# with address}} {{city}} to be honest

Comment: for a small example like that it doesn't matter much, but when you have deeply nested objects (for a calendar, for example, year.month.week.day.name) it gets incredibly cluttered. Again, a first world developer problem, but thought I'd search for an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to have Angular recognize what scope it is in, and not require the extra `walrus.`, `zombie.`, or (worst of all) `walrus.address.`?

I'm not aware of any way to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to be the correct answer. I think I could explicitly create a child scope, but that wouldn't be any cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

For the not nested 'walrus' you could do this:

```
angular.extend($scope, $scope.walrus);
```

This will extend the $scope with the walrus object and now you can use {{ bubbles }} in the template!

I used extend, but i really don't know if this is the right way to do what you want!